# Storage profile error when deploying new machine using json template

Tags: azure, scripting, json

I'm trying to deploy two vm's in an avset using visual studio 2015.

I get the error message below when I attempt to deploy:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 2:03:59 AM - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines '31' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "details": [
      {
        "target": "vm.properties.storageProfile.networkProfile",
        "message": "Could not find member 'networkProfile' on object of type 'StorageProfile'. Path 'properties.storageProfile.networkProfile', line 1, position 893."
      },
      {
        "target": "vm.properties.outputs",
        "message": "Could not find member 'outputs' on object of type 'Properties'. Path 'properties.outputs', line 1, position 1072."
      }
    ],
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The request message is invalid."
  }
}'
At C:\Users\Base\Desktop\Azure-Deploy.ps1:5 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name DCDeploy -ResourceGroupName  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 2:03:59 AM - Could not find member 'networkProfile' on object of type 'StorageProfile'. Path 'properties.storageProfile.networkProfile', line 1, position 893.
At C:\Users\Base\Desktop\Azure-Deploy.ps1:5 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name DCDeploy -ResourceGroupName  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 2:03:59 AM - Could not find member 'outputs' on object of type 'Properties'. Path 'properties.outputs', line 1, position 1072.
At C:\Users\Base\Desktop\Azure-Deploy.ps1:5 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name DCDeploy -ResourceGroupName  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

My template is below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "stdAdminUserName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "stdAdminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_GRS"
      ]
    },
    "faultDomains": {
      "type": "int"
    },
    "updateDomains": {
      "type": "int"
    },
    "applicationid": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "sharedservice": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "msdref": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "project": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "costcentre": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "templateref": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "environment": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "operatingsystem": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "deploymentzone": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "shutdownschedule": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "avSetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "vmInstances": {
      "type": "int"
    },
    "vmSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "vmDiskSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "networkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "networkResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "vmNicNamePrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "vmNamePrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "VNetID": "[resourceId(Parameters('networkResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', Parameters('networkname'))]",
    "SubnetRef": "[resourceid(variables('VNetID'), '/subnets/', Parameters('subnetName'))]",
    "stdVMImagePublisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
    "stdVMImageOffer": "WindowsServer",
    "stdWindowsOSVersion": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
    "stdVHDContainerName": "vhds",
    "VMOSDiskNamePrefix": "VMOSDisk",
    "VMDATADisk1NamePrefix": "DataDisk1VM",
    "VMDATADisk2NamePrefix": "DataDisk2VM"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[Parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "tags": {
        "displayname": "[Parameters('storageAccountName')]",
        "applicationid": "[Parameters('applicationid')]",
        "sharedservice": "[Parameters('sharedservice')]",
        "msdref": "[Parameters('msdref')]",
        "project": "[Parameters('project')]",
        "costcentre": "[Parameters('costcentre')]",
        "operatingsystem": "[Parameters('operatingsystem')]",
        "deploymentzone": "[Parameters('deploymentzone')]",
        "shutdownschedule": "[Parameters('shutdownschedule')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "accountType": "[Parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[parameters('avSetName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('avSetName')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "platformUpdateDomainCount": "[parameters('updateDomains')]",
        "platformFaultDomainCount": "[parameters('faultDomains')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[concat(Parameters('vmNicNamePrefix'), copyindex(1))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "copy": {
        "name": "nicLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmInstances')]"
      },
      "tags": {
        "costcenter": "[Parameters('costcentre')]",
        "environment": "[Parameters('environment')]",
        "project": "[Parameters('project')]",
        "role": "vmnic",
        "templateref": "[Parameters('templateRef')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                 "id": "[variables('SubnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmInstances'), copyindex(1))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', Parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/', Parameters('avSetName'))]",
        "nicLoop"
      ],
      "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmInstances')]"
      },
      "tags": {
        "applicationid": "[Parameters('applicationid')]",
        "costcentre": "[Parameters('costcentre')]",
        "deploymentzone": "[Parameters('deploymentzone')]",
        "displayname": "[concat(parameters('vmInstances'), copyindex(1))]",
        "environment": "[Parameters('environment')]",
        "msdref": "[Parameters('msdref')]",
        "operatingsystem": "[Parameters('operatingsystem')]",
        "project": "[Parameters('project')]",
        "sharedservice": "[Parameters('sharedservice')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "availabilitySet": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets',parameters('avSetName'))]"
        },
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[Parameters('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[concat(parameters('vmInstances'), copyindex(1))]",
          "adminUsername": "[Parameters('stdAdminUserName')]",
          "adminPassword": "[Parameters('stdAdminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[variables('STDVMImagePublisher')]",
            "offer": "[variables('STDVMImageOffer')]",
            "sku": "[variables('stdWindowsOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "name": "[concat(variables('VMOSDiskNamePrefix'), copyindex(1))]",
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "[concat('http://', Parameters('storageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/', variables('stdVHDContainerName'), '/', variables('VMOSDiskNamePrefix'), copyindex(1), '.vhd')]"
            },
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          },
          "networkProfile": {
            "networkInterfaces": [
              {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(Parameters('vmNicNamePrefix'), copyindex(1)))]"
              }
            ]
          }

        },
        "outputs": {
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your template has a mistake, you lose a `},` at the end of `storageProfile`, so `networkprofile` becomes a attribute for storageProfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use NotePad++ check, network profile is in your storageProfile. But they are juxtaposed attributes. The error log also tells you this.

[image]

You could try following template.

```
    "properties": {
        "availabilitySet": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets',parameters('avSetName'))]"
        },
        "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "[Parameters('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
            "computerName": "[concat(parameters('vmInstances'), copyindex(1))]",
            "adminUsername": "[Parameters('stdAdminUserName')]",
            "adminPassword": "[Parameters('stdAdminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
                "publisher": "[variables('STDVMImagePublisher')]",
                "offer": "[variables('STDVMImageOffer')]",
                "sku": "[variables('stdWindowsOSVersion')]",
                "version": "latest"
            },
            "osDisk": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('VMOSDiskNamePrefix'), copyindex(1))]",
                "vhd": {
                    "uri": "[concat('http://', Parameters('storageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/', variables('stdVHDContainerName'), '/', variables('VMOSDiskNamePrefix'), copyindex(1), '.vhd')]"
                },
                "caching": "ReadWrite",
                "createOption": "FromImage"
            }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
            "networkInterfaces": [{
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(Parameters('vmNicNamePrefix'), copyindex(1)))]"
            }]
        }

    }
```

Note: `outputs` is a attribute parallel to `resources` and `variables`.

Comment: Hi Thanks again Walter, I understand the outputs is equal to variables and resources, it could be the lack of sleep or just plain dense, but I'm getting this error, so looks like its not seeing the output. Have I missed a bracket somewhere and its been seen in the resources: Error -- 'Could not find member 'outputs' on object of 
type 'TemplateResource'. Path 'properties.template.resources[3].outputs', line 245, position 20.'. --

Comment: Hi, in your template you don't print output, you could delete it. The error means output is under `resources`. You need move it.

Comment: Thanks Walter, I had a feeling it was a bit mixed up. First I think I need to pass out. I appreciate your help (again) hope you have a great day..  thanks again :)

Comment: Hi, if you have other error log, you could compare with this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-2-vms-loadbalancer-natrules/azuredeploy.json). :)

Comment: @NorrinRad Hi, does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414226/set-azure-dns-setting-from-csv-file-for-network-interface-cards/47425588#47425588) work for you?

Comment: Hi  this was very helpfl thanks. Sorry about the late reply, been ill and not been working, hope you're well :)

Comment: @NorrinRad I am so sorry for you. I hope you feel better soon.

Comment: hi where are you in the world?

Comment: I am in China. I am Microsoft Azure supporter.

Comment: Hi, we could chat in this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159465/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-norrin-rad

Comment: Microsoft has a support center in Wuxi, China --:)

Comment: hi I sent you a message in that chat room .. anyway might be easier on Email my email is rajinder.rahul@gmail.com 

Comment: Fine, my e-mail is `v-shshui@hotmail.com`. If you have Azure issue, maybe you could contact me. We are free to support --:).

Comment: @NorrinRad In my country, I need go home, if you have question, you could e-mail to me.  --:)